# Simple ActiveRecord Association problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am learning Rails, so this is a very simple problem.

I am trying to associate Users<-Posts in the classic one-to-many style- user's own posts.

Here are my models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body
  belongs_to :user  
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

I also created the necessary migration:

```
class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :posts, :user_id
  end
end
```

The problem I'm facing is trying to get rails to see all of this and correctly build the association.

When I call:

```
@user = User.first
@user.post.build
```

I get a

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `post' for #<User:0x10319fbc8>
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be `user.posts` but `post.user`

Answer (score 2):

If a user `has_many` Posts the correct call is:

```
@user.posts.build
```

Notice the plural posts.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared the association is `User` model as `has_many :posts` so the association will be available to you by using `@user.posts.build` instead of `@user.post.build`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a has_many relationship so:

```
@user.posts.build
```